# Can a single volume be assigned multiple drive letters?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8

I am working on migrating data across many disparate drives onto one massive Windows 8 Storage Space.

Problem I have is that many of my programs reference various drive letters to acces their libraries, files, music, movies, etc.

Is there any way I can, for example, have any reference of drives D, E, F, and G all point to the new drive S:?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, use the `subst` command in the command line: `subst NewLetter: OldLetter:\`

For example, to assign the current `C:` drive the letter `H:` as well: `subst H: C:\`

See `subst /?` for more info.

```
Associates a path with a drive letter.

SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path]
SUBST drive1: /D

  drive1:        Specifies a virtual drive to which you want to assign a path.
  [drive2:]path  Specifies a physical drive and path you want to assign to
                 a virtual drive.
  /D             Deletes a substituted (virtual) drive.

Type SUBST with no parameters to display a list of current virtual drives.
```

Comment: Awesome, I was going to suggest `mklink`, but this works just fine.

Comment: @cable729 That would not be possible. Directory junctions and symlinks are NTFS features, so you cannot assign a drive label as a link.

Comment: I successfully created a link from C:\d to D:\

Comment: @cable729 But you cannot link `C:` (the label) to `D:`. You linked a folder to a drive, not a drive label to a drive. Also, this requires an NTFS partition mounted as `C:` to put the link *on*, which defeats the purpose of consolidating drives as in the question (since the whole point is to reduce the number of partitions/combine data on one partition).

Answer (score 3):

You can't run subst as admin, but as a regular user instead, or your "new" drive won't be recognized. Once I ran the "regular" command prompt it worked.

Reference: [Windows Explorer not recognizing subst'd drives](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1253737)