# Assign a second letter to a Mapped Network Drive, without it appearing in This PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-drive

I currently have a network drive assigned to letter O:. A few of my co-workers have it mapped to a letter Z:, and that's how they post their links to me. From [this](https://superuser.com/a/494482/702762) question I've found I can `subst` that letter, and that works fine.

However, it created a `Disconnected Network Drive` `Network Location` within `This PC`, which just looks ugly.

Is there anyway I can hide that, or assign another letter implicitly?

Mapping the same network location as Z also "works", but that also shows two network locations.

[image: Screenshot of the Drives]

Comment: Why can't you just force the mapping configuration you want, and make is so, only Administrators can map network drives?

Comment: I would just remove the O mapping and map it as Z. One letter, and its uniform to what everyone else has.

Comment: I agree. This is a problem that shouldn’t exist. Admins should be deciding who has what drive maps and it should be completely out of the hands of the end user. Or, this is the kind of stuff that happens.

Comment: @Ramhound Not entirely sure what you mean?

Comment: @Appleoddity Well, I'm the end-user in this scenario I suppose, and my company's IT doesn't bother mapping the drives for us, especially since we could be on multiple projects at once, so having them do it would be a headache and expensive. Plus what if I wanted to do it on my personal computer for personal use? How would I solve it then? This isn't a problem that would never exist.